# How to get latest 3 records of each month of each year?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a single query in mysql to get latest 3 records of each month for each year ?  Or it should be done through Loop ?

i.e.

```
YEAR 2011

january 

Record 1
Record 2
Record 3

May 

Record 1
Record 2
Record 3

September 

Record 1
Record 2
Record 3

YEAR 2012

August 

Record 1
Record 2
Record 3

Nov 

Record 1
Record 2
Record 3

Dec 

Record 1
Record 2
Record 3
```

and so on.

A guess that it can be achieved with loop but not sure what's the better way to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using some sample application.
Remember I did this so you can use naming convention as per your desire.

First created database table as below.
I have named this table 'threemonth'

```
id auto_increament,
title varchar 255,
created date
```

title is just to sure for non repeating result,

Now create one php file and make database connection and all.

Now copy paste below query inside that page.

```
SELECT YEAR(created) as stat_year,
       MONTH(created) as stat_month,
       COUNT(*) as stat_count,
       title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(created) as FinalResult,
       id
FROM
      `threemonth`
GROUP BY stat_year,stat_month
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Above query will out put something like below.

```
stat_year = 2012
stat_month = 12
stat_count = 2
FinalResult = comma separated date listing becaue of concating result.
title and id
```

Now when displaying record, display it as your desire.

Just explode comma separated created field and only display first three record and you are done.

Comment: Let me try it and then i will tell you

Comment: try it using navicat for mysql you will see what u doing wrong and other more help regarding mysql function that we might never know.

Comment: By the way what are the database table structure.? so i can help you more.

Comment: its simply (id, title, name, and date) where date is current time stamp